# Parked Domain not working in cpanel

Tags: dns, cpanel

My website Main Domain in cpanel is currently set to **xyz.com** . I have added a new parked domain  **abc.com** which is pointing to the same document root as my main domain **xyz.com** . The problem is my parked domain is not directing to my main domain, instead an error page shows up. How do i fix this? Below is the screenshot of the error page : [image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try to ping the parked domain name "abc.com". If it resolves to the same IP as your main domain then this may be a temporary DNS issue. You can ping the domain using below steps :

### Press Windows + "r" to open command prompt >> then type cmd >> then type the below and hit enter :

### ping abc.com

If it points to the same IP as your main domain, then try accessing the website in http://anonymouse.org/

If it works fine in the above website then please try clearing the DNS cache on your local machine using the below steps on windows machine:

1.Windows + "r" to open command prompt >> then type cmd >>
2.In the command window type the following and then hit enter: ipconfig /flushdns